# Opening a WPF Window from a WinForms application (.Net 4.5.2/Win 7/ 32 Bit)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have recently come across an issue on Windows 7 32-bit OS with .Net 4.5.2 installed. I have an application that is Winforms and opens a modal WPF Window. However, since we installed .Net Framework 4.5.2, these windows do not open properly, once the window .ShowDialog() is called it takes about 15-20 seconds (mouse turns to a pointer for several seconds and the winforms window becomes unresponsive) and then we receive the following exception:

[image]
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Not enough quota is available to process this command

The weird thing is once this exception is thrown and I choose to "continue", the next time I attempt to open the window, it opens instantly and no exception is thrown.

The following is a simplified version of what I am using to open the window. (When I run this code, the application does not throw the exception but it does hang for the 15-20 seconds)

```
    private void OpenWpfWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WPFWindow testWindow = new WPFWindow();

        testWindow.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        testWindow.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;

        System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper helper = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(testWindow);
        helper.Owner = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[0].Handle;

        testWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

We do not experience this issue with Windows 7 and With .Net 4.5 installed

Comment: Does this happen if you call Show() instead of ShowDialog()?

Comment: I have Windows 8 64-bit .NET 4.5.2, VS2013 update 4 and that code ran fine for me.  I set the Winforms app to x86 and it still worked.  To be specific: I created a new Winforms app, new WPF app, added references from Winforms to WPF app + PresentationBase and others.  New button, click event pointed to your OpenWpfWindow function.  Run app, click button, WPF window appears.  It took about 5 seconds to appear.

Comment: There is a chain of posts on the MSDN forums that seem to imply that showing the window could fill the message queue.  Follow the trail of links starting here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e94283a-76be-42b3-98e6-a8e18c4e43de/invisible-wpf-dialog-filling-up-windows-message-queue?forum=wpf

Comment: -When I call show, the same behaviour exists.

-This works fine in Windows 8.1 with 4.5.2 installed, It is just windows 7

Comment: I have seen this thread but will look further into it. I have tried the FrameDispatcher unsuccessfully but maybe there was something I was missing.

Comment: Your program has called PostMessage() *ten thousand* times.  Sure, takes a while.  After which the operating system decided there was no longer any point in allowing it to call that function again.  You exceeded the quota on the message queue, the internal data structure that stores messages.  It acts like a buffer, the basic way you for example can type keystrokes even if the app is unresponsive and they don't get lost.  Nobody can tell why it isn't responsive from a screenshot.

Comment: All thia program is is a button that calls this method. My reason for posting here is to see if there are any solutions to why it is calling post message 10000 times, how did you find this and what would you like me to provide if this isn't enough. Please expand on your criticism if you are going to comment

Comment: If you can reproduce this in a very simple app as you're claiming, in different Windows 7 machines, I'd suggest you to submit a bug [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio). They're probably gonna be able to help you better there. And then post it back here once you found a solution to help others in case no acceptable answer is posted :-)

Comment: What is in the WPFWindow class?  You didn't mean Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls.WpfWindow right?  I assumed WpfWindow is just some random System.Windows.Window.

Comment: It is just a WPF control that extends Window and contains one checkbox UI element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue turned out to be an issue in .NET 4.5.2 (in Windows 7) regarding the initialization of touch devices and there is a hotfix solution from Microsoft.

The WPF application starts the Windows Touch Input Service (wisptis.exe), even when no touch devices are present, resulting in a delay, meanwhile the message queue is flooded and the WPF Window creation fails.

The hotfix can be found here: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3026376/